# Approximate binomial distribution with binomial distribution with smaller n

Tags: probability, markov-chains, biology

Given a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ (number of trials) and $p$ (probability of success), is it possible to approximate it using a smaller $n$ by adjusting the size of $p$?  [EDIT:] More specifically, what I have in mind as an approximation is that e.g. the probability of $k$ successes in an $n=500$ distribution with a specially chosen $p$ is close to the probability of $10k$ successes in an $n=5000$ distribution for a given $p$, or better yet, that the first probability is close to the sum (or average) of probabilities for $10k-5$ successes and $10k-4$ successes, and ..., and $10k+4$ successes.

What would I like to approximate?  Well, the mean and variance, of course, and maybe skew and kurtosis, but what I'd really like is an overall similar probability mass function.

Context: I'm simulating changes in gene frequencies in a population of organisms using a Wright-Fisher model with natural selection, which is to say that I use a binomial distribution with $n$ = population size and $p$ = a value that may depend on fitness differences.  I use the distribution to create a transition matrix from states in which the gene has frequency $k$ to states in which it frequency $k'$.  Then starting from a state in which all probability is on one frequency (usually), one multiplies as many times as needed to calculate distributions over frequencies at future times.  So what I really want is to approximate distributions at different times as the multiplication is iterated.

One phenomenon I'm interested in is how fast probabilities of fixation (i.e. of $k=0$ or $k=n$) become large, and how the difference between probabilities of these two states changes over time.  $n$ has a big effect on this.

The reason that I want to use a smaller $n$ is simply that the calculations I'm doing (not described here) become too slow for $n>500$.

Maybe this can't be done, or must be done differently depending on the size of $n$ and $p$, or must be done differently for different time steps.  Maybe the approximation of the transition matrix will involve using another distribution (Poisson, Gaussian, Beta) or a diffusion approximation?  I'm open to all suggestions, but would prefer to end up with a transition matrix(s) that I can multiply.

Comment: Too little info here for me to be really helpful. Comments: (a) You refer to _Bernoulli_ with parameters $n$ and $p.$ Bernoulli is only for $n=1$ trial; suspect you mean _Binomial._ (b) Usually, it is a bad idea to use an approximation in a transition matrix that is raised to high powers. Any error in the approx can get magnified in unpleasant ways. (c) You say comp is too slow for $n > 500.$ Are you using optimal methods on a computer? (d) One usually approx's a Binomial dist'n by a Poisson dist'n, not another binom with a different $n$. But in view of  (b) I'm not sure you should use approx.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET.  These comments are helpful.  "Bernoulli" was a typo;  fixed now.  Clarified approximation idea.  (b) makes a lot of sense, unfortunately. Using the best computational methods I can in OCaml, and looking for further optimizations, but this may be the limit.  The computation is not a simple matrix multiplication, but  so-called [hi-lo method](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540647751).  I'm compiling to native binaries and splitting it between multiple CPU cores. The matrix multiplication parts are quite fast using the Owl library; it's the hi-lo code that's the bottleneck.

Comment: Just to clarify, the hi-lo method is a sort of complicated analog of matrix multiplication.  What I said in the question about multiplying matrices was strictly speaking incorrect.  Explaining what I'm really doing with the matrices seemed like it would just confuse things unnecessarily.

Comment: Not familiar with hi-lo, so best not to speculate.

Comment: @BruceET, understood.  But I know the hi-lo method, and can say that that I think your point (b) about magnification of errors plausibly applies. :-(   On the other hand, if I had a strategy for approximation, it would be easy to test it, on a few cases, at least.  I might have to wait several days for an $n=5000$ simulation to run, but then I could compare its output with the approximation.  An approximation that seems to work would allow experimentation, and then any crucial result could be re-run with the large $n$ value.

Comment: Then see what happens with a Poisson approximation. Use Poisson mean $\lambda$ to be Binomial $np.$ But before using the approximation look at distribution tables of Poisson and binomial to see if the approximation is realistic.